# Can one line mysql commands be easily stored and re-used?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I find myself constantly typing in long commands such as:

mysql> SELECT Cust_Num, Cust_Name_Full, Email FROM customers;

Is there a way to save this command as, say, "CInf" and execute it with that simple shortcut command like this:

mysql> CInf;     ( = mysql> SELECT Cust_Num, Cust_Name_Full, Email FROM customers; )

I'm thinking of something analogous to a DOS batch file, where you can simply type the name of the batch file, without even needing the .bat extension.

Also, where do I store these mysql "batch files" (note: these aren't .bat files to be run from a command window, these are run from the mysql> prompt). With DOS I'd have a C:/bat folder and I'd put C:/bat in the path environment variable. How do I do a similar thing for mysql?

Comment: Maybe you want [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html) or [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/views.html) of common queries. If you're doing this sort of thing constantly, do yourself a favour and write a script or a web interface to it.

Comment: I discovered the possibility of using myqsl> \. myscript.sql but I don't know where to store the script file (myscript.sql) so the mysql prompt can find it. The MySql manual says "create a text file" to save batch commands but it doesn't say where to put the text file

Answer (score 2):

Mysql doesn't have "macros", but if your statements are select queries (like your example) you can create views:

```
create view clnf as
SELECT Cust_Num, Cust_Name_Full, Email
FROM customers;
```

Then to use

```
select * from clnf;
```

The other approach is to store your SQL in files, then from the mysql prompt use the `source` command:

```
mysql> source file_name
```

which executes the contents of the SQL file as if you had pasted it in to the window.

Comment: Where do I save the source file so it can be found by the mysql prompt? Or do I have to type in the full path of the source file every time? That could be as tedious as entering the SELECT command...